# React Native: Check if component is returned to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm wanting to refresh a component once it has been returned to from a child component. I currently have a dogs page that lists dogs that a user can click on. The user can delete a dog on the dog page and I would like this change to be reflected in the dogs page when they press 'Back' to return to the dogs page. Does anyone know of a callback or any other way I can detect that a user has returned to the dogs page from a dog page?

Comment: There probably is a `this.props.navigator.pop()` somewhere. But we'd need some in order to provide a correct and complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem is to add a callback from your top level component into the rendered navigator. This would be a hacky but quick solution. To address this issue on a solid base I would encourage you to try [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux), it has a single source of truth, so removing a dog (via an action) would cause all other data dependent components to rerender. To get started I would recommend this [egghead course](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux).